# How do I work with JFXtras in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to work with `JFXtras` in Eclipse. I downloaded their `ZIP` file and I do not know how to work with gradle.  The download is available here: http://jfxtras.org/

The instructions say:

> ```
> Set your environment variable JAVAFX_HOME to the directory that contains rt/lib/jfxrt.jar.
> cd jfxtras
> gradlew build
> ```

But, is there an easy way around this ?
Or, an easy way to do this ?